Unable to pass a nullable variable as non-nullable after null check in Dart
Minimum reproducible code:
void foo(int? i) {
  bar() {
    if (i != null) {
      // Error in both lines:
      baz(i); // Line-1
      i++; // Line-2
    }
  }
}

void baz(int i) {}

Problem:
Why is there an error in both lines, especially Line-1? If I comment out Line-2, the error in Line-1 goes away.

Note: I am not looking for a solution but rather an explanation as to why there's an error in Line-1, when null has already been checked using the if condition.

The variable i is not a variable local to the function bar. It is a parameter of foo. That means foo can change it, while bar is running, or do other shenanigans with it.
It would work, if you had put the code directly into foo. It would work, if you passed i as a parameter to bar. Maybe under a different name to avoid confusion.
To quote the Dart documentation on this:

If you check a local variable with nullable type to see if it is not null, Dart then promotes the variable to the underlying non-nullable type

Emphasis mine.

To be clear, i is a local variable. It's just that promotion of local variables fails if there are assignments to them in a closure, because the compiler doesn't know when, if, or how often that closure is run. (And it's limited by being a one-pass analysis, so it doesn't come back and recognize that nobody ever calls that closure.)

Everything is a "local" variable in the end. Even a "global" is local to the program as a whole. The question is local to what? i is local to foo, it is not local to bar for the exact reason you named. So code inside bar cannot promote i.

The Dart language specification defines three kinds of variables: Global (top-level or static, per program/isolate), instance (per object instance) and local (per activation record). Function parameters, try/catch variables and variables declared inside function bodies are local variables. For promotion, there is no difference between local variables introduced by parameters and by var-declarations in the body. It is true that a captured local variable cannot be promoted, and that being captured and modified can also prevent being promoted anywhere, even in the original function.
